# Une mise en relief : "C'est à Paris que" vs "C'est à Paris où"

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

> C'est à Paris que les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre.
>
> C'est à Paris où les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre.

Quelle phrase serait plus correcte? Merci!

Answer (score 5):

Il n'y a pas de phrase plus correcte que l'autre, car les deux sont valides. Elles n'ont cependant pas exactement le même sens.

1. > Dans quelle ville les bistrots représentent-ils un véritable art de vivre ?
   > C'est à Paris **que** les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre.
2. > Où préfères-tu passer tes après-midi ?
   > C'est à Paris **où** les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre.

La première phrase est la plus courante. Une virgule peut séparer *Paris* et *où* dans la deuxième pour montrer qu'on est plus proche d'une juxtaposition que d'une subordination.

Comment: Excellent réponse. Je suis d'accord avec l'usage d'une virgule dans le 2eme exemple: C'est à Paris, où les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre. La même construction peut être employée dans une phrase du type: C'est à Paris, où les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre, que les clients passent le plus de temps en terrasse.

Answer (score 3):

Not native speaker. Normally, speaking about place and time one would use the turn

> c'est/ce sont...où

E.g.

> C'est le musée où nous avons rencontré Dimitris.

But, with a preposition or an adverb the turn

> c'est/ce sont...que

is used.

E.g.

> C'est dans le musée que nous avons rencontré Dimitris.

So, for your sentence, it should be:

> **C'est à Paris que** les bistrots représentent un véritable art de vivre